# htaccess rewriting user pretty url to perform query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Say I have a site mysite.com, which is a wordpress site.

I already have the following rewrite rules to remove index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if I go to mysite.com/?blog_type=a-blog-type I get the proper page with only the blogs of that type

What I would like, is for the user to be able to type in mysite.com/blogs/a-blog-type/  and have that acutally do the query, but keep on displaying /blogs/a-blog-type/

I've looked at many similar answers on here, but most seem to make it so that it just redirects from the query, to the pretty url, which I don't want, as the pretty url just leads to a 404 error as it's not doing the query.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrite rule will take any `mysite.com/blogs/a-blog-type/` URL and rewrite it to `mysite.com/?blog_type=a-blog-type`. So `mysite.com/blogs/a-blog-type/` would be displayed to the user, but `mysite.com/?blog_type=a-blog-type` will be loaded.

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]*)((/)?)$ ?blog_type=$1 [nc,l]
```

**EDIT:** So here's how your config will now look:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]*)((/)?)$ ?blog_type=$1 [nc,l]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Now do I put this inside the <IfModule>? or make another <IfModule> after the one I already have?

Comment: You can put it in the same one. As long as you put it before the index.php rules it should work. (So I'd put it directly after "RewriteBase" in your example). I've updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't seem to be working.  if I did something like: RewriteRule ^blogs$ www.google.com [nc,l] just to test it, should that redirect it to google.com?

Comment: Yes, that should direct to Google, but only if you don't put a "/" at the end of the URL when you test. You can also use RewriteLog to see exactly what is happening behind the scenes, it's extremely helpful for debugging. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: thanks, I'll look into rewriteLog, as it seems like it's doing nothing... but I know the file is being accessed because index.php is gone, and if I typo something, the whole site is inaccessable.  I'll get back to  you once I see whats going on with the Log

Comment: ok, I've figured out my issue, but now to figure out how to fix it.  The issue is with the "Permalinks" plugin. I have to have it set to /%postname% in order for ALL of the rest of the site to work, with proper nice named URLs, as soon as I put that to default, the rewriterule you gave me works perfectly. but once put back to the custom /%postname% the blogs rewrite rule dies.  thoughts?

Comment: I'm afraid the specifics of Wordpress are outside my area of knowledge :( It's probably best to create a new question specifically about the new issue with the Permalinks plugin. From the description, it sounds like the plugin probably has it's own Rewrite config which might be conflicting with your current one.